# While running python script as another user (with sudo), input string taken as variable name

Tags: python, command-line, sudo, nameerror

I have a simple python script, test.py:

```
x = input("Enter string")
print("Entered str: ", x)
```

I want to run the script as another user; lets call him scratch:

```
sudo -u scratch python test.py
```

The program waits for the console input. When I enter "abc", I encounter the following error:

```
Enter stringTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    x = input("Enter string")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
```

I am not sure about the reason behind this and the fix for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` behaves differently in Python 2.x and 3.x. The other account has Python 2.x set as its default, or has a Python 2.x executable first in its `PATH`. Your usual account, on the other hand, is using a Python 3.x executable. Probably the best way to do this is to use the full path to the Python executable you want to use i the script's "shebang" line. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

(This path may need adjusting for your system. Try typing `which python` in your account to see what it's using.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the code is using `input()` in a Python 2.7 environment (the other users' default python version probably). Try using `raw_input()` instead.

`input()` in a 2.7 behaves as a `raw_input()` followed by an `exec()` which is why it throws the `NameError`.

The code would run fine on a Python 3.x interpreter.

Comment: My guess is raw_input() has been removed from python 3.x (It's not there in 3.4). But nice details. Thanks!